# Why OpenID Connect let a client initiate authentication for another client

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I am using OpenID Connect in Keycloak as an authentication solution and I've just encountered the following scenario.

- Client `A` sends an authorisation request to the Authorization server and provide `redirect_url` of  client `B` in that request.
- Authorization server authenticate the user and redirect the user to the provided `redirect_url`(which is for client `B`) with `authentication_code`.
- Client `B` communicates with Authorization server with its own `client_id` and secret and takes its token.

I want to know why OpenID Connect has allowed this
process, is it a normal thing for a client to initiate authentication for another client? Why the issued `authentication_code` is not bound to the client who has initiated the authentication and why it the `authentication_code` can be used by other client with other `client_id`?

*Note: I know that validity of `redirection_url` will be checked in that process but I want to know why authorization code is not bound to client_id itself.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's indeed possible in Keycloak then it's a problem of the implementation, not the spec. The Oauth spec in section [4.1.2.](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6749#section-4.1.2) indicates this for the authorization code:

> The authorization code is bound to the client identifier and redirection URI.

As for the redirect URI it should also be verified and client A should be able to use redirect URI of client B only if that other redirect URI was whitelisted for client A.

The [Proof Key for Code Exchange](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7636) is also something which would prevent such a use of an Oauth flow as you described here.

Comment: Thank you for you precious answer, but I do not understand  your description about Redirect URI, If I accept redirect URI of client `B` in client `A`, what happened to the binding of the Authorization code to Client `A`? you mean when I define redirect URI of client `B` in the whitelist for client `A` then that Authorization code can also be used by client B? Could you please refer to protocol, when it is mentioned that it is possible?

Comment: The authorization code should still be bound to client A, but, maybe for some weird reason, you want to redirect the user to client B, nonetheless. Of course, still client B won't be able to exchange the code for tokens as the code is bound to client A. What I meant in the answer is that generally client A should not be able to use client's B redirect URI at all, as the URI should be verified against the client A's whitelist. It is technically possible to add client B's URI to that whitelist, but I don't see a valid reason for that.